# Silence JAX initial messages

Tags: python, jax

I am using JAX with CPU. Everytime I use it I get a message:

```bash
Platform 'METAL' is experimental and not all JAX functionality may be correctly supported!
2024-01-27 15:56:46.164447: W pjrt_plugin/src/mps_client.cc:563] WARNING: JAX Apple GPU support is experimental and not all JAX functionality is correctly supported!
Metal device set to: Apple M1

systemMemory: 16.00 GB
maxCacheSize: 5.33 GB
```

This is crowding my terminal, how do I disable it?

Answer (score 0):

The log warning from JAX uses Python's built-in logging; you can silence it in the normal way:

```py
logger = logging.getLogger("jax._src.xla_bridge")
logger.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
```

The other warning appears to be coming from the METAL plugin source, and I'm not sure how to disable it. Unfortunately, it's a closed-source plugin so there's no way to inspect the code to see how the warning is being issued; I'd suggest getting in touch with the developers.

> I am using JAX with CPU.

If you're not intending to use the METAL plugin (which targets Apple GPU, not CPU), then I would suggest uninstalling it:

```
$ python -m pip uninstall jax-metal
```